# AVD cannot be created Ok is disabled

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have eclipse juno 4.2.1 Android SDK already installed, I've created an Android application and while creating new AVD 
the **Ok** button is always disabled although I've determined all it's specifications

here is the specifications I've entered

[image]

I don't know why
Any ideas!
Thanks.

Comment: Yea dear the problem was in the SDK. the strange was I've already updated the SDK and when i tried to check it and already the whole new packs was marked as installed

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No system Images You installed,

Go to `window->Android SDK Manager`, and download System images for avd for that specific target

Answer (score 2):

You can check if you have any spaces in the "AVD Name".

Answer (score 1):

just restart eclipse.Although you download it still needs a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CPU/ABI section on your screenshot. It is clearly saying that there is no system image installed for the targeted version.

Go to SDK Manager and install '**ARM EABI v7a System Image**' for your target version.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

After I follow to above solution what I download the system image, but the disable of OK button cannot be reactivated by system image.  I tried to refine the parameter setting that RAM is less than 758M bytes (less than hardware configuration) for HTC One X.  There is alright to reactivate the "OK" button.

The program of SDK Manager is required to check the available RAM in your machine whether for the testing in simulation of SDK Manager.  I tried to use less RAM size in ADV virtual device and then system can enable "OK" button instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to select a skin from the drop-down menu to enable the ok button.

Answer (score -1):

Possible alternative solution

I banged my head on this for several hours until I found out that the default location was C:\username path\SDKs or something, where Android was installed on my system to D:\sdks\android_sdk_windows. So, changing the Eclipse Android directory to D:\sdks\android_sdk_windows fixed it.

I also heard that it may help things if you install the Android SDK to a path without spaces.

Hope this helps someone keep some hair.