# Why I Can not create AVD in Android ?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

I have download the eclipse an Android SDK. I just import existing project and try to run. But It show error message that,'No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add a new Android Virtual Device?'. I have try to create new AVD. But I can not create new AVD. OK button is not enable in the Create New Android Virtual Device. I have search the solutions in the stack overflow for this problem. I have found lots of results. And I have try everything. Still now I can not create AVD.

I have try these solutions [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821081/avd-cannot-be-created-ok-is-disabled) , [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128/avd-manager-cannot-create-android-virtual-device)

Please let me know what I have to do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't create AVD or test any application with AVD after update build tools to 22.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215958/cant-create-avd-or-test-any-application-with-avd-after-update-build-tools-to-22)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22216119/3330969

Comment: Ok.. I accept it is a repeated question. But where is the solution?

Comment: You should read the answer too.

Comment: This is a known issue, we'll have an update out with the fix shortly. That mean there is no solution for this issue??

Comment: At present no solution. Instead AVD you can use real device ( if you have any )

Comment: Sorry.. I don't have.. :-( .. Any way, thanks for the answer..!!

Comment: @user2845346 Once cut your ADT bundle from current drive and paste it into any other drive then try. Hope it works. And select snapshot option when you try to create emulator.